# How to let default values come from the database?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Why does the `user` object still have `Nothing` for `createdAt` and `updatedAt`? Why are those fields not getting assigned by the database?

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
  email String
  createdAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  updatedAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  deriving Show
|]

main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
  runMigration migrateAll
  userId <- insert $ User "saurabhnanda@gmail.com" Nothing Nothing
  liftIO $ print userId
  user <- get userId
  case user of
    Nothing -> liftIO $ putStrLn ("coulnt find userId=" ++ (show userId))
    Just u -> liftIO $ putStrLn ("user=" ++ (show user))
```

Output:

```
UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}}
user=Just (User {userEmail = "saurabhnanda@gmail.com", userCreatedAt = Nothing, userUpdatedAt = Nothing})
```

Comment: I guess you were hoping that `default=CURRENT_TIME` would be used during insertion to fill in `Nothing`s, maybe? But I would bet that `default=CURRENT_TIME` is actually used only during migration. Then again I have never used the library these come from (which appears to be `persistent-template` -- might be worth mentioning in your question).

Comment: One big issue with a huge reliance on Template Haskell is that when your generated code doesn't do what you expect, you either have to manually analyze it (and it is just *hideous*) or you must simply *know* whats happening, probably be being the person who wrote the code to generate the code that broke. Even if you do find the problem, extracting a tiny bit of code and changing it is impossible if it is all generated in one go. Your best bet may be to not use this `default=..` thing and to write this feature yourself.

Comment: Which SQL backend are you using? I recommend accessing your SQL database from the command line and checking what the table definition is (you want something like `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo` for MySQL and `\d+ email` for Postgres.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda see my solution below using SQLite triggers.

Comment: To my eyes, the behavior of persistent looks right. Maybe I'm too used to the ecosystem... If you want the time of `creation` and `update`, why don't you pass the proper time instead of `Nothing` ? Also why is it modeled as `Maybe` ?

Answer (score 6):

(Edit: see solution below using triggers)

#### The problem: Default values don't override explicitly setting a column to NULL

Per the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value to use for the column if no value is explicitly provided by the user when doing an INSERT.

The issue is that when Persistent is doing the insert, it's specifying the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns as `NULL`:

```
[Debug#SQL] INSERT INTO "user"("email","created_at","updated_at") VALUES(?,?,?); [PersistText "saurabhnanda@gmail.com",PersistNull,PersistNull]
```

To reach this conclusion, I modified your snippet to add SQL logging (I just copied the source of `runSqlite` and changed it to log to STDOUT). I used a file instead of in-memory database just so I could open the database in a SQLite editor and verify that the default values were being set.

```
-- Pragmas and imports are taken from a snippet in the Yesod book. Some of them may be superfluous.
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Data.Time
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Control.Monad.Logger
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Text

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
  email String
  createdAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  updatedAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  deriving Show
|]

runSqlite2 :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m)
          => Text -- ^ connection string
          -> SqlPersistT (LoggingT (ResourceT m)) a -- ^ database action
          -> m a
runSqlite2 connstr = runResourceT
                  . runStdoutLoggingT
                  . withSqliteConn connstr
                  . runSqlConn

main = runSqlite2 "bar.db" $ do
  runMigration migrateAll
  userId <- insert $ User "saurabhnanda@gmail.com" Nothing Nothing
  liftIO $ print userId
  user <- get userId
  case user of
    Nothing -> liftIO $ putStrLn ("coulnt find userId=" ++ (show userId))
    Just u -> liftIO $ putStrLn ("user=" ++ (show user))
```

Here's the output I get:

```
Max@maximilians-mbp /tmp> stack runghc sqlite.hs
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-3.10 from implicit global project's config file: /Users/Max/.stack/global/stack.yaml
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "user"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"email" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"created_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,"updated_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME)
[Debug#SQL] CREATE TABLE "user"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"email" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"created_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,"updated_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME); []
[Debug#SQL] INSERT INTO "user"("email","created_at","updated_at") VALUES(?,?,?); [PersistText "saurabhnanda@gmail.com",PersistNull,PersistNull]
[Debug#SQL] SELECT "id" FROM "user" WHERE _ROWID_=last_insert_rowid(); []
UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}}
[Debug#SQL] SELECT "email","created_at","updated_at" FROM "user" WHERE "id"=? ; [PersistInt64 1]
user=Just (User {userEmail = "saurabhnanda@gmail.com", userCreatedAt = Nothing, userUpdatedAt = Nothing})
```

#### Edit: Solution using triggers:

You can implement `created_at` and `updated_at` columns with triggers. This approach has some nice advantages. Basically there's no way for `updated_at` to be enforced by a DEFAULT value anyway, so you need a trigger for that if you want the database (and not the application) to manage it. Triggers also solve for `updated_at` being set when executing raw SQL queries or batch updates. Here's what this solution looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_created_and_updated_at AFTER INSERT ON user
BEGIN
UPDATE user SET created_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updated_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE user.id = NEW.id;
END

CREATE TRIGGER set_updated_at AFTER UPDATE ON user
BEGIN
UPDATE user SET updated_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE user.id = NEW.id;
END
```

Now the output is as expected:

```
[Debug#SQL] INSERT INTO "user"("email","created_at","updated_at") VALUES(?,?,?); [PersistText "saurabhnanda@gmail.com",PersistNull,PersistNull]
[Debug#SQL] SELECT "id" FROM "user" WHERE _ROWID_=last_insert_rowid(); []
UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}}
[Debug#SQL] SELECT "email","created_at","updated_at" FROM "user" WHERE "id"=? ; [PersistInt64 1]
user=Just (User {userEmail = "saurabhnanda@gmail.com", userCreatedAt = Just 2016-02-12 16:41:43 UTC, userUpdatedAt = Just 2016-02-12 16:41:43 UTC})
```

The main downside to the trigger solution is that it's a slight hassle to set up the triggers.

#### Edit 2: Avoiding `Maybe` and Postgres support

If you'd like to avoid having `Maybe` values for `createdAt` and `updatedAt`, you can set them on the server to some dummy value like so:

```
-- | Use 'zeroTime' to get a 'UTCTime' without doing any IO.
-- The main use case of this is providing a dummy-value for createdAt and updatedAt fields on our models. Those values are set by database triggers anyway.
zeroTime :: UTCTime
zeroTime = UTCTime (fromGregorian 1 0 0) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
```

And then let the server set the values through triggers. Slightly hacky, but in practice works great.

#### Postgresql triggers

The OP asked for SQLite but I'm sure people are reading this for other databases as well. Here's the Postgresql version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_timestamps()   
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN
            NEW.created_at = now();
            NEW.updated_at = now();
            RETURN NEW;   
        END;
        $$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_timestamps()   
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN
            NEW.updated_at = now();
            RETURN NEW;   
        END;
        $$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER users_insert BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_timestamps();
CREATE TRIGGER users_update BEFORE UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_timestamps();
```

Comment: Good sleuthing! You win a small bounty.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer, this really made my day :)

Comment: @MaxGabriel I believe with the way Yesod is written, your solution is the most pragmatic. However, the issue still remains that Yesod does not have a way to represent "Unspecified" values. In this context, you have a value present, a NULL value, and an **unspecified** value. From a row-insertion point of view, an **unspecified** value should NOT be treated as NULL, because that prevents the DB from filling-in the defaults.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda file an issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

> The default attribute has absolutely no impact on the Haskell code
>   itself; you still need to fill in all values. This will only affect
>   the database schema and automatic migrations.

```
do
  time <- liftIO getCurrentTime
  insert $ User "saurabhnanda@gmail.com" time time
```

Comment: But @SaurabhNanda is retrieving the record fresh from the database before printing it.

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to have a single source of "truth" in system design? In this case, isn't the DB the right place for this "truth" -- i.e. the default values of createdAt and updatedAt?